# ViewController called manually is over-ridden by "Show" Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6

I have the following code in my custom method:

```
(IBAction)checkContinue:(UIButton *)sender {

if ([category.text isEqualToString:@""])
 {
    [self displayErrorMsg:@"Category Name cannot be empty"];

    [category becomeFirstResponder];

 }
```

//The else part doesn't work at all. When I click **"Continue"** the second view controller is shown and in that the error message in the **"If"** part is displayed.

```
else{

 //This code will help to navigate from Menu types to Create Menu Screen

   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"sw_contmenu" sender: self];
}
}
```

I have 2 segue for my MenuViewController: **sw_contmenu** and **sw_newmenu**, which will be executed from 2 different methods.

Problem: When I run the code and click **Continue** button, the above function is invoked with null values but the else part of the function doesn't work.

[image: 2 view controllers with 2 segue names]

Comment: Have you add a breakpoint to see if the `else` part is executed?

Comment: Breakpoint is not useful. It does not show anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra action segue that is causing the second view controller to be pushed into view at the same you are handling the button press. These two operations are in conflict.

Deleting the action segue and adding a Show segue between the first view controller and second view controller should fix the problem.

Comment: I do not understand what your trying to say.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the updated text in the text field cannot be read until the keyboard is dismissed. Does that help?

Comment: I tried but still the same problem. I am running the ios app thru xcode 6 for testing.

Comment: Is there an action segue on your button under Triggered Segues in the Connections Inspector?

Comment: Yes, it says - action -> show and below show it is Create Menu.

Comment: I understand the problem you're having a little better now. It appears you have a table view that contains the categories. What you need to do is either read the value from the table view correctly or have the category text field be updated with the value from the table view. Your code only shows that you are reading the value from the text field but your screenshots indicate that a category is being selected using the table view. If that is the case, you'll need to read the value from the table view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93441/discussion-between-thegame-and-daniel-zhang).